# How can I set Structural Navigation to "Display only the navigation items below the current site" via JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, navigation, current-navigation

I currently have JavaScript that sets the navigation, however it currently sets it to:

> "Structural Navigation: Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings"

I cant seem to get it to set to:

> "Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site"

We are using a SharePoint Online environment and we have built the JavaScript into the page layout.

This is the code I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var scriptBase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";   

    $.getScript(scriptBase + "sp.runtime.js",function(){

        $.getScript(scriptBase + "sp.js",function(){

            $.getScript(scriptBase + "sp.publishing.js", modifyNavigation);

        });
    });

function modifyNavigation(){


    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();


    var currentWeb = context.get_web();     


    var webNavSettings = new SP.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings(context, currentWeb);


    var navigation = webNavSettings.get_currentNavigation(); 

    navigation.set_source(1);

    webNavSettings.update();

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

        console.log("Navigation set");  

    },function(sender,args){

        alert(args.get_message());

    });


}
```

With this code I end up with the following result:
[image: Navigation]

Is it possible to have the code set the bottom radio button?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that's still actual, but I found the solution to this problem.

In addition to setting the WebNavigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source to "PortalProvider", which you do in your code by calling

```
navigation.set_source(1);
```

you also need to update the property "__NavigationShowSiblings" of the web object.

e.g. in PowerShell you can do this (and it works):

```
$web.AllProperties["__NavigationShowSiblings"] = "False";   
$web.Update()
$ctx.Load($web.AllProperties)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

In JSOM I think you could do something like this (haven't tried but found the snippet)

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
this.properties = web.get_allProperties();
this.properties.set_item("__NavigationShowSiblings", "False");
ctx.load(web);
web.update();
```